# Как задать градиентную прозрачность блоку div?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с контентом. Как можно сделать так, чтобы была прозрачность с левого края, при этом этот блок (с контентом) постепенно становился видимым вплоть до 15% его ширины, и потом, начиная с 85% и заканчивая 100% снова становился прозрачным. В итоге должен получится эффект, будто его края прозрачные (со всем содержимым блока в этой области).

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum ipsumipsumLorem ipsum ipsumipsumLorem ipsum ipsumipsumLorem ipsum ipsumipsumLorem ipsum ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: А уточните, что значит в данном случае "прозрачность"? Под этим блоком по краям должно проступаться какое-то другое изображение? Или просто края должны становиться как бы невидимыми?

Comment: Да, именно края должны становиться невидимыми, прозрачными. И в не зависимости от заднего плана, он будет просвечиваться и эта прозрачность будет заметна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прозрачный блок не получится сделать, но можно залить поверх цветом фона.

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #444;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.test::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, transparent 15%, transparent 85%, white);
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum ipsumipsumLorem ipsum ipsumipsumLorem ipsum ipsumipsumLorem ipsum ipsumipsumLorem ipsum ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: прозрачность вполне себе можно сделать, если использовать `rgba()`-формат

Comment: Прозрачность дива? Ну я бы посмотрел как на див наложить rgba.

Comment: диву можно бэкграундом задать градиент, которому передавать цвета в rgba

Comment: градиент-то можно и без rgba задать. тут вопрос в том чтобы точно так же становился ГРАДИЕНТНО прозрачным контент.

Comment: Спасибо, интересная и рабочая идея. Дополнить еще pointer-events: none; , чтобы мышь не реагировала на этот слой и можно считать что все идеально.